# Scala map is not gettin updated

Tags: scala, hashmap

I've written the following solution in scala for the three sum problem.
However the value in the map `sums` never gets updated.
Can someone explain why doesn't it get updated?

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
object Solution {
    def threeSum(nums: Array[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
      val sums = Map[Int, ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]]().withDefaultValue(ListBuffer())
      for((a, aIndex) <- nums.view.zipWithIndex) {
        for((b, bIndex) <- nums.view.zipWithIndex) {
          if(aIndex != bIndex){
            val sum = a + b
            List(a, b).sorted match {
              case List(a, b) => {
                sums(sum) += ((a, b))
                println(sums)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      val result = ListBuffer[List[Int]]()
      for(c <- nums){
        val neg = c * -1
        if(sums.contains(neg)){
          val sumSet = sums(neg).toSet
          for((a,b) <- sumSet) {
            val triplet = List(a, b, c).sorted
            result += triplet
          }
        }
      }
      result.toList
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the usual sorts of debugging techniques such as adding `println`s to find out what's going on in the code?

Comment: Yes. The println only prints an empty map every time.

Comment: Maybe because you are never put something to your map (using `+` operator for example)?!

Comment: `withDefaultValue` never causes entries to be added to a `Map`, it only changes what happens when you do a lookup and the key is missing. So when you do `sums(sum) += ((a, b))`, `withDefaultValue` returns a new `ListBuffer`, and then you add an item to that `ListBuffer`, and then.... nothing happens, that `ListBuffer` just gets discarded. You need to actually make entries in the map

Comment: Remember that the default Scala map is **immutable**.